# XLSX.writeメソッドは、修正したフォントカラーのスタイルを保持できないのか？

Tags: javascript, excel

javascriptを用いて、エクセルの修正を試みている際に生じた事象についてです。
(ライブラリは、xlsx使用 https://www.cdnpkg.com/xlsx/file/xlsx.full.min.js/?id=78603#)

指定したセルに入っている値のフォントカラーを変更する命令をする。
その命令後に、そのファイルをダウンロードするが、毎回フォントカラーが変更されずに、出力される。

ワークブックに適用された後の状態をログとして出力したが、フォントカラーは変更されている。
今回で言うと、D6セルだが、問題なくフォントカラーが変更されている。

```
D6
: 
s (スタイル情報)
: 
font (フォント情報)
: 
color (色情報)
: 
rgb (RGB色コード)
: 
"FFff0000"
t
: 
"n"
v
: 
"5000"
w
: 
"255"
```

ここまでは問題ないことを踏まえると、エクセルファイルが書き込まれる際に、何らかの原因でエラーが起きて、フォントカラーが元に戻ってしまっているのではないかと思う。

この事象を回避するために、どのような対応を取ればいいか教えてください。

Comment: 関連の度合いは不明ですが、これらの記事が参考になるかもしれませんね。[Changing font color while adding row in exceljs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45055510/9014308), [Create an excel file with a few styles using client side JavaScript (if possible using js-xlsx library)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40486860/9014308), [How to add styles to an excel column with xlsx javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74865329/9014308), [SheetJS xlsx-cell styling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50147526/9014308)

Comment: いただいたURLをもとに内容を確認しいろいろと試してみると、問題なくフォントカラーを変更できました！
ありがとうございました。

原因は、ライブラリがxlsx.full.min.jsであったことだったため、
xlsx.jsに修正して、解決できました。

Comment: 解決されたなら、情報共有のために状況・原因・対処方法などの詳細を自己回答・自己承認(自己承認の場合は48時間経過してから)してみてください。[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

xlsxライブラリは使わないので、
頓珍漢な回答になっているかもしれません。

'ffff0000'
↓
'#ff0000'
と設定してみても変わりませんか？

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。
アドバイス通り修正してみましたが、フォントカラーは変更されませんでした。。